# Fastest Variable Set in Java

Tags: java, performance, structure

I need Structure (Arraylist, LinkedList, etc) that is very fast for this case:
While the structure is not empty  I search the structure for elements that satisfy a condition , lets say k, remove the elements that satisfy k and start over for another condition lets say k+1.

e.g.:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= 1000000; i++) {
  structure.add(i);
}

d = 2;

while (!structure.isEmpty()) {
  for(int boom : structure.clone) {
    if (boom % d == 2) {
      structure.remove(boom);
    }

    d++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could start by not cloning and using an `Iterator` (you can remove from an iterator). As to "fast", well, try it out.

Answer (score 2):

If the elements are primitives, then the fastest structure will most probably be a specialized primitive collection (e.g., [trove](http://trove.starlight-systems.com)). Following references for boxed primitives is a nearly sure cache miss and this probably dominates the costs.

I wouldn't suggest a `LinkedList` for the same reason: It's dead slow due to cache misses.

If the order is unimportant, than an `ArrayList` is perfect. Instead of removing an element, replace it by the last one and remove the last array element. This is an `O(1)` operation and doesn't suffer from the bad spatial locality.

If the order is important, you can build your own `ArrayList`-like structure. Instead of removing an element, you mark it for removal e.g. in a `BitSet` or in a `boolean[]`. Finally you perform the removal in one sweep by moving all elements to their right position and adjusting the length. The optimized loop will most probably look similar to [CharMatcher.removeFrom loop](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java#1057).

A simpler solution would be to use an `ArrayList` and copy all surviving elements to another one. I'd bet it'd beat the `LinkedList` hands down. As a minor GC-friedly optimization you can work with two lists.

Answer (score 0):

[LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) should be fastest for this case. Use the iterator explicitly (structure.iterator()) and call the remove method of the iterator instead of calling structure.remove(element)!

Comment: I'd bet that `LinkedList` is slow due to cache misses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your exact use case, but here's one note.

If you have your predicates P1 .. PN pre-compiled, available, and if you are not modifying the contents of the collection and if your predicates are not dependent on each other, you might want to create a composite predicate, like bundle up N predicates in some logical order, and then in only one iteration over your collection perform the filtering method.

As for data structure, I'd think if it like this:

If my filtering predicates will be totally arbitrary, then a list should be OK to use.

In some more specific cases with very limited and strict value sets, you might consider a tree-like or a graph-like structure, where you could have some master nodes which would denote that property "property1" has value "value1". In case you wanted to drop all items where "property1" value is "value1" you could tell that master node to remove all his children (and that they should detach themselves from any other parent master nodes they might have).

Answer (score 0):

#### Sorted List data structure

If you construct the lists yourself you can consider using a `sorted` data-structure. It will give you best search performance( `log n` complexity so it is very fast).

#### Linked List data structure

LinkedList gives you constant time element removal but random access doesn't have constant complexity (is slow).

You will have to benchmark if a LinkedList or a sorted list would be faster for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If your elements are `int`s, I suppose bit set would be the fastest data structure for this task. Iteration would be slightly slower than through array list (even not standard `java.util.ArrayList`, only primitive specialization), but remove ops cost nearly nothing, while removes from any array list are quite expensive.

Note, you can gain much by working directly with `long[]` as bit set and performing bitwise operations by hand, because `java.util.BitSet` is not very performance-focused. But, of cause, start with `BitSet`.